# Where are the Aptana Studio docs?

Tags: aptana

When I click on Documentation at the http://www.aptana.com/support.html web site, it goes instead to the doxs for appcelerator. Does anyone know where the 'getting started' docs are for Aptana studio?

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.ssv-comm.de/downloads/dokumente/mht_igw922_aptana_studio_ide.pdf) might be helpful. You can also [check](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/wiki/Getting-Started) and try googling more.

Answer (score 0):

inside Aptana

1. Help -> Help Contents or Dynamic Help
2. Contents -> Workbench User Guide -> Getting Started -> Basic tutorial

There is also the GitHub doc https://github.com/aptana/studio3/wiki/Getting-Started

As Aptana was taken over by Appcelerator, it is now also called Appcelerator Studio.  The Docs are here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Appcelerator+Studio